# On bilinear and quadratic forms: Why isnt the variance a bilinear form?

Tags: abstract-algebra, statistics, functions, bilinear-form, descriptive-statistics

The example Im using comes from statistics but its not limited there. This is a question about bilinear and quadratic forms.

This might sound like a dumb question. I can readily see from its properties that variance is not a bilinear form. The variance of a sum is not the sum of the variances in the general case.  I dont need it proven to me.  Im just kind of surprised that it isnt bilinear. Here's why:

We know that $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{Cov}(X,X)$, correct?  Thus, variance is just a special case of covariance.  But covariance is a bilinear form. Somehow variance is not.

Im having a logical error somewhere. Can someone reconcile?

It has occurred to me that the variance is a single argument function while the covariance is two argument. Naturally bilinear forms require two arguments, but a variance can easily be interpreted as a two-argument covariance. I thought that the number of arguments might have something to do with it, but it seems a rather arbitrary thing.  How can the abstract properties of functions be determined by an artifact of man-made notation?

Answer (score 4):

If $B(X,Y)$ is a bilinear form, then $Q(X):=B(X,X)$ is a **quadratic form**. This isn't particular to variance and covariance. Take the dot product of vectors, for example: $\|x\|^2=x\cdot x$ is not a bilinear form (it isn't even a function of two variables, which is a prerequisite to be **bi**linear - this is not just "man-made notation"), but a quadratic form.

One can convert any symmetric bilinear form to a quadratic form, and also back again using the polarization identity $Q(X+Y)=Q(X)+2B(X,Y)+Q(Y)$.

Comment: That last paragraph, although very useful, also has a limitation: you can do this only if the field in question does not have characteristic two. If it does, you can't go from $Q$ to $B$ because it involves division by ... uh... $2$.

Comment: I never meant to imply that it was only true for variance and covariance. It was just the example I came across.  I do appreciate the answer. I didnt realize all bilinear functions became quadratic when the argument is repeated.